# How to shorten this rational function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, rational-functions

Determine a value for the constant b so that we can shorten the expression for the function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{2x^2+bx-30}{x+3}$. Shorten the expression.

Here is the step by step solution we got:

The zero point for the denominator $x+3$ is $x=-3$

The function $f$ is defined when $x\ne-3$

We can shorten the expression only if the denominator and numerator have a common factor. The numerator has the factor $x+3$ only if $-3$ is the zero point in the numerator.

We determine the constant b:

The numerators value is zero for the variable value $-3$.

$2\cdot\left(-3\right)^2+b\cdot\left(-3\right)-30=0$

$b=-4$

Now I don't understand why x is replaced with $-3$ above. What is the reason behind it, why can't it be for example be $-4$?

edit: need an easy explanation, I'm not too good at math.

Comment: The tag [linear-algebra] should not be used in this question. Please consider using [algebra-precalculus] instead.

Answer (score 1):

By long division, there exist polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$, with $\deg r(x)<\deg(x+3)$ such that
$$2x^2+bx-30=q(x)(x+3)+r(x).$$
Once we have $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ we can simplify $f(x)$ as follows:
$$f(x)=\frac{2x^2+bx-30}{x+3}=\frac{q(x)(x+3)+r(x)}{x+3}=q(x)+\frac{r(x)}{x+3}.$$
Now note that $r(x)$ is a constant, i.e. a number, because $\deg r(x)<\deg(x+3)$, and so
$$r=r(-3)=q(-3)(-3+3)+r(-3)=2(-3)^2+b(-3)-30.$$
In particular we see that $f(x)$ reduces to a polynomial if $r=0$, which is equivalent to $b=-4$.

Comment: What do you mean by deg?

Comment: The degree of the polynomial

Comment: This explanation is too hard for me, i'm not so good at math.