# How to shorten this rational expression?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, rational-functions

Determine a value for the constant b so that we can shorten the expression for the function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{2x^2+bx-30}{x+3}$. Shorten the expression.

Here is the step by step solution we got:

The zero point for the denominator $x+3$ is $x=-3$

The function $f$ is defined when $x\ne-3$

We can shorten the expression only if the denominator and numerator have a common factor. The numerator has the factor $x+3$ only if $-3$ is the zero point in the numerator.

We determine the constant b:

The numerators value is zero for the variable value $-3$.

$2\cdot\left(-3\right)^2+b\cdot\left(-3\right)-30=0$

$b=-4$

Now I don't understand why x is replaced with $-3$ above. What is the reason behind it, why can't it be for example be $-4$?

edit: need an easy explanation, I'm not too good at math.

Comment: You want to check if $-3$ is a zero of the numerator, so you just have to replace $x$ by $-3$ and see when this vanishes.

Comment: They propose to shorten it by factoring the numerator.  If one factor is $(x+3)$ then we can cancel that with the denominator.  So the rest is finding value of $b$ so that $x-3$ is a factor of the numerator.  That is the same as a value of $b$ so that $x=-3$ is a zero of the numerator.

Comment: What is short? If I choose $b=0$, $\frac{2x^2-30}{x+3}$ looks shorter to me.

Comment: did you ask the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4223715/306553) twice?

Comment: This theorem is why https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that "shorten" means that some simplification/cancelling occurs in the rational function.

This occurs when there is a common factor of the numerator polynomial and the denominator polynomial.

The only factor of the denominator polynomial is evidently
$$x+3.$$
So we require that $x+3$ is a factor of $2x^2+bx-30$, so that it will simplify.

By the polynomial remainder theorem, $x+3$ is a factor of a polynomial $P(x)$ iff $P(-3)=0$, hence $x+3$ will be a factor of $2x^2+bx-30$ iff
$$2(-3)^2+b(-3)-30=0$$
$$18-3b-30=0$$
$$3b=-12$$
$$b=-4$$

Hence, $f(x)$ "shortens" when $b=-4$. We can use polynomial division or factoring to show that $2x^2-4x-30=(2x-10)(x+3)$, hence
$$f(x)=\frac{(2x-10)(x+3)}{x+3}$$
$$f(x)=2x-10~\text{ }\forall x\neq -3.$$

Comment: Now I think I got it! If my example would be divided with $x+5$, then I would need to use $f(-5)$ (always the opposite)?

Comment: Yes, to see if $x+5$ is a root of both the numerator and denominator. You need to plug in $-5$ into both the numerator and denominator.